# Offensive-security files content is unreadable with wget

Tags: linux, utf-8, character-encoding, wget, ansi

I'm trying to download some URLs using wget. I get files with no problem except for this link [Offensive-Security-ICQ](https://www.offensive-security.com/pwbonline/icq.html) and any other link on www.offensive-security.com.

I tried on both Linux and Windows with many trials and alot of search, but in vain.

I use this command "wget https://www.offensive-security.com/pwbonline/icq.html"

The resulted file shows this symbols and it is ANSI decoded [image]

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: What makes you think the download failed ? This might just be the content of the file you downloaded... Oh, and please avoid posting useless screenshots, this gives no additional information and costs a lot more (disk space, network...)

Comment: Could you edit question and paste the exact command-line you used to get that file. Could help.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the server does not return the html page but a zipped version of it. The file you get is identified as a gzip compressed data:

```
$ file icq.html
icq.html: gzip compressed data, from Unix
```

So you can simply unzip it and you get the correct html page.

Why is the server doing that: not sure, but it's probably some default setting that has been left as is, so you can download faster.

How can one directly donwload the html content: probably by sending some common user agent and header, so that the server thinks that its a common web browser doing the request instead of a download tool.

This can be done with `wget` using some options, for example, this should work:

```
wget --header="Accept: text/html" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" https://www.offensive-security.com/pwbonline/icq.html
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both solutions worked just fine. My regards.